# Variable en Inicializador SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swift4

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    import SwiftUI
    import QGrid
    
    struct VerCanales: View {
        
        var categoria:String
        @ObservedObject var canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
        
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView{
                QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                    NavigationLink(destination:VlcPlayerDemo()){
                        Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
                    }
                }
                
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("CHANNELS AVAILABLE"))
        }
    }
```

La variable "categoria" viene de la vista anterior como un parámetro y necesito pasarla como un parámetro al @ObservedObject  pero tengo el siguiente error: "Cannot use instance member 'categoria' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

Supongo a que se refiere que no puedo usar la variable ya que no se ha inicializado.

Soy nuevo en el lenguaje y he buscado pero no puedo encontrar una buena solución

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he resuelto de una manera mas sencilla de esta forma:

```
struct VerCanales: View {
    
    private var categoria: String
    @ObservedObject private var canales: CargarCanales
    
    init(categoria: String) {
        self.categoria = categoria
        self.canales = CargarCanales(categoriaID: categoria)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            QGrid(self.canales.listaCanales, columns: 3){item in
                NavigationLink(destination:VlcPlayerDemo()){
                    Text(item.name).frame(width:400, height:50)
                }
            }
            
        }.navigationBarTitle(Text("CHANNELS AVAILABLE"))
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como la solución, así ayudas a otros usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se trabaja con `@ObservedObject` se necesita inicializar el valor real del objeto antes de utilizar.

En tu clase solo el `init` así:

```
class CargarCanales: ObservableObject {
    var categoriaID: String

    init() {
        self.categoriaId = ""
    }
}
```

Hay que inicializar el objeto en la vista y guardar el objeto para su uso:

```
struct VerCanales: View {
        
    var categoria: String
    @ObservedObject var canales: CargarCanales = CargarCanales()

    init(categoria: String, canales = CargarCanales()) {
        self._canales = ObservedObject(wrappedValue: canales)//Almacenamos el objeto de tipo ObservedObject
        self._canales.wrappedValue.categoriaId = categoria//Asignamos el valor de categoría al objeto almacenado
        self.categoria = categoria
    }
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(canales.categoriaId)//Imprime Test        
    }
}

struct ContetnView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(categoria: "Test")
    }
}
```

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta, intente lo que mencionas sin resultado......De pronto no me hice entender bien....Lo que necesito es poder usar la variable categoria que viene de la vista anterior, la clase del Observable esta correcta. En resumen, necesito capturar la variable categoría y enviarla como parámetro del Observed, pero me da error "Cannot use instance member 'categoria' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available" .. La clase está así:  `init(categoriaID:String){}`

Comment: He modificado la respuesta, se debe trabajar con el `wrappedValue` para modificar o asignar la data de ese tipo de objeto.